How does YOLO predict objects that are proportionally smaller than a single grid cell?
In YOLO, I notice that, if the idea is to have each grid cell be responsible for predicting some $B$ # of bounding boxes for objects that belong to its center, how does YOLO predict an object that is proportionally entirely contained within a single grid cell, or is that not possible? It seems to me that, once the tensor is a feature map with length # feature maps and a certain width and height such as 7x7, each cell for any feature map is a single scalar, so I don't see how any cell can encapsulate information about an object centered at this cell's dimensions within that cell. If this were possible it seems to imply that the tensors throughout feature extraction would have to be carrying specific numerical coordinate information in addition to feature information, which I don't think makes sense as the tensors are max pooled and cnns are already largely translational invariant.
So am I off, or is it that, if the final grid is $m$ X $m$, then only objects that span at least the entirety of 1 cell in this grid could be detected, and we simply workaround this by choosing a pretty big-ish grid? I think the original YOLO paper mentions difficulty with small objects but it seems to be in the context of small objects in groups and difficulty having higher error for incorrect localizations for smaller objects.
I also have another question, which might not be appropriate to append to this one: Once a cnn layer in YOLO returns a tensor of length $B(C+5)$, (where $B$ is # boxes for each grid cell, $C$ the # of classes, and $5$ the length of the tuple - x,y,width/height,confidence), it seems to me the necessary data should already be there to run non max suppression on, but it seems it might likely be beneficial to treat this tensor as still consisting of feature maps and allow an MLP to potentially find greater insight or organization with how the predictions of boxes are arranged in this tensor, and then run NMS on the output. My second question is, has anyone ever tried this without using any linear layers at the end and if the results were significantly different?
